# Is there any way to publish the build for the same test group automatically on firebase?

Tags: firebase, bitrise, firebase-app-distribution

I'm starting to use the firebase app distribution linked to bitrise.
I would like to every successful build on bitrise it publishes on firebase app distribution for the same group, without need to on every build I open the firebase console and add the group for that build.

It's a flutter app, I don't know if bitrise offers a specifically feature for that.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

[image]

There are 2 ways you can do this:

1. Add testers individually in Firebase App Distribution step's `Testers` field.
2. Add tester groups in Firebase App Distribution step's `Test Groups` field.

For (2), you need to have already created group on Firebase App Distribution.

This will be saved and you won't need to add test group every time build is triggered.